# ScalaJs Test with utest

Tags: scala.js, utest, playscalajs

I am working on a cross built ScalaJs project and have written ScalaJs Tests using utest. It was initially working fine and test cases did compile and gave result but now I am suddenly getting the below mentioned error. Please tell me as to what may be wrong and how can it be corrected.

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
org.mozilla.javascript.JavaScriptException: scala.scalajs.runtime.UndefinedBehaviorError: An undefined behavior was detected: undefined is not an instance of java.lang.String (Lorg_scalajs_testinterface_internal_BridgeBase.sjsir#143)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1018)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:815)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:109)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3102)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:107)
    at org.scalajs.jsenv.rhino.RhinoJSEnv$$anonfun$org$scalajs$jsenv$rhino$RhinoJSEnv$$setupCom$2$$anonfun$4.apply(RhinoJSEnv.scala:341)
    at org.scalajs.jsenv.rhino.RhinoJSEnv$$anonfun$org$scalajs$jsenv$rhino$RhinoJSEnv$$setupCom$2$$anonfun$4.apply(RhinoJSEnv.scala:341)
    at org.scalajs.jsenv.rhino.RhinoJSEnv.loop$1(RhinoJSEnv.scala:406)
    at org.scalajs.jsenv.rhino.RhinoJSEnv.org$scalajs$jsenv$rhino$RhinoJSEnv$$comEventLoop(RhinoJSEnv.scala:412)
    at org.scalajs.jsenv.rhino.RhinoJSEnv$$anonfun$org$scalajs$jsenv$rhino$RhinoJSEnv$$internalRunJS$5.apply(RhinoJSEnv.scala:216)
    at org.scalajs.jsenv.rhino.RhinoJSEnv$$anonfun$org$scalajs$jsenv$rhino$RhinoJSEnv$$internalRunJS$5.apply(RhinoJSEnv.scala:215)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.scalajs.jsenv.rhino.RhinoJSEnv.org$scalajs$jsenv$rhino$RhinoJSEnv$$internalRunJS(RhinoJSEnv.scala:215)
    at org.scalajs.jsenv.rhino.RhinoJSEnv$AsyncRunner$$anon$1.run(RhinoJSEnv.scala:116)
org.scalajs.jsenv.ComJSEnv$ComClosedException: JSCom has been closed
    at org.scalajs.jsenv.rhino.RhinoJSEnv$ComRunner.receive(RhinoJSEnv.scala:164)
    at org.scalajs.testadapter.ComUtils$.receiveResponse(ComUtils.scala:42)
    at org.scalajs.testadapter.ComUtils$.receiveLoop(ComUtils.scala:21)
    at org.scalajs.testadapter.ComUtils$.receiveLoop(ComUtils.scala:16)
    at org.scalajs.testadapter.ScalaJSTask.execute(ScalaJSTask.scala:61)
    at sbt.TestRunner.runTest$1(TestFramework.scala:76)
    at sbt.TestRunner.run(TestFramework.scala:85)
    at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
    at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
    at sbt.TestFramework$.sbt$TestFramework$$withContextLoader(TestFramework.scala:185)
    at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
    at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
    at sbt.TestFunction.apply(TestFramework.scala:207)
    at sbt.Tests$$anonfun$9.apply(Tests.scala:216)
    at sbt.Tests$$anonfun$9.apply(Tests.scala:216)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:44)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:44)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] Could not run test com.knoldus.DashboardClientTest: org.scalajs.jsenv.ComJSEnv$ComClosedException: JSCom has been closed
```

Comment: You're trying to cast an `undefined` into a `String` somewhere. I recommend you use Node.js instead of Rhino for running your code, so that you get better stack traces.

Comment: thanx for your reply....was able to trace the problem and fix it !! :)